# 500 internal server error perl/Database

Tags: mysql, database, perl, web

I am accessing a database from my perl script and am trying to put an if statement in to be able to query different things based on what the user picks.

It works perfectly without the if statement but when I add the if statement it gives me the 500 error.

So this one works:

```
my $query = "SELECT * FROM cars";
```

And this one does not:

```
if( $model eq "All"  ){

    my $query = "SELECT * FROM cars";

}
```

Comment: echo the value of $model before the if statement.

Comment: echo didnt show anything, broke before it got to that line. I am pretty sure it is all because if I use chrome and inspect element and look at the headers "All" is sent for model.

Also just found this error:

Global symbol "$query" requires explicit package name at

Comment: OK so I answered my own question by trial and error. I moved an else statement that came after the if to before. and took the else away. So query would get set to something no matter what, and I had to take the my away from infornt of the $query in the if statement. Now all is well!

Apparently I am not knowledgeable to answer my own question on this website...it wont let me lol

Comment: Variables declared with `my` have a scope of the nearest enclosing block. Which in your case means that `$query` is not declared outside your if statement.

Answer (score 4):

Variables declared with my have a scope of the nearest enclosing block. Which in your case means that `$query` is not declared outside your if statement.

The solution is to place the declaration in the right scope, e.g. before the if-statement.

With `use strict` in effect, as implied by your reported error `Global symbol "$query" requires explicit package name`, this will cause a 500 error.

Comment: This will indeed cause the variable to not be defined after the block, but will this cause a 500 server error?

Comment: @Konerak With `use strict` - which is implied by the error the OP reported getting - yes. Because the script will not compile, only report errors.